# What are some good films about cycling?

Tags: bike-culture, movie

Can you recommend high quality cycling-centric films? Can you recommend good sources (for example, publishers, distributors, vendors, etc.) to locate these films?

Comment: IMO this question is too broad. For example, here is a 71 page forum thread with the same idea and many links: [click](http://mtb-bg.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=11239&start=2100).

Comment: @Vorac, are you serious? Would it be specific enough if it was, "Are there any other good films about the Paris-Roubaix", for example? It's a good-natured question that's already garnered enthusiastic responses. Plus the forum you linked to is in Russian!

Comment: @Vorac - question is deliberately broad. Personal recommendations across the whole gamut of film about cycling is what interests me.  Question now edited for clarity.

Comment: I'm afraid @Vorac's correct - in fact I remember a very similar question got closed about 6 months ago. Closure reason would either have been because it was too broad (i.e. too many possible answers) or because it was looking for opinion-based answers - hint, you could pre-empt the latter with a slight reword of the question. But that having been said, I think this question will serve as a useful resource, so I'm *not* going to vote to close it.

Comment: I agree that it is likely to be closed, though a great topic. Perhaps viable as a big-list type community wiki with one movie per answer.

Comment: I agree with @David - Especially given the question portion about sources to locate the films. This is not a great exchange question, but potentially a wonderful community wiki question.

Comment: Make it community wiki. It seems ideal for that. Each answer is one movie.

Comment: Whats a film - are the Danny Maskell type short clips films?

Answer (score 10):

Old but still worthwhile: [Breaking Away](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078902/).

Comment: Yeah, that was the first one to come to my mind.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Yeah, I was a bit surprised it wasn't pretty much the first one to be mentioned...

Comment: Much of it is antiquated, of course, but it reflects "real" competitive cycling representative of the era, and just technical enough to interest bikies while not driving away other viewers.

Answer (score 6):

A few of my guilty pleasures:

*Hard-boiled:*

- The Greatest Show On Earth ('74 Giro)
- [Death on the Mountain: The Story of Tom Simpson](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b0074rgb)

*Soft-boiled:*

- [The Flying Scotsman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0472268/), Graeme Obree biopic
- Quicksilver
- [The Triplets of Belleville](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286244/) (originally released in UK as *Belleville Rendez-vous*)

Comment: Innart! It's fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

Because I'm a mountain bike guy, and I think the stories and shots are way more interesting (sorry roadies):

- [Where The Trail Ends](http://www.wherethetrailends.com)
- [Strength in Numbers](http://www.anthillfilms.com/strengthinnumbers/)
- [Life Cycles](http://www.lifecyclesfilm.com/)
- [Won't Back Down](http://www.wontbackdownfilm.com)
- [Rad Company](http://www.redbull.com/us/en/bike/films/1331645565522/rad-company-mountain-bike-film)

And of course all the old-school freeride films like Kranked.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of classics for you...

[A Sunday in Hell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxBTVU9JDrA)

[The Stars and The Water Carriers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUIr9LG1juw)

Comment: Maybe a brief description, for those of us unfamiliar??

Answer (score 1):

[Hell on Wheels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell_on_Wheels_%282004_film%29) is a German movie portraying Erik Zabel and Rolf Aldag during the Tour de France 2003. It gives quite some insights into cycling on that level (while it ignores doping and we meanwhile know that the participants did quite some doping during that time ...)

Answer (score 1):

[Blood Sweat Gears](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HU1ZGE) is a documentary on Garmin Cycling Team, a good alternative to watching TdF dvds.

Answer (score 1):

It's no Breaking away, but check out [American Flyers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088707/) too. You've got your Kevin Costner, cycling, iconic scenes, and Russian bogeymen.

Comment: I love to annoy my ride buddies with the occasional "Enough of this Sunday ride, LET'S HURT A LITTLE BIT!!"

Answer (score 0):

[The Sufferfest](http://www.thesufferfest.com/) offer motivational/training videos.

Also, [Bromley Video](http://www.bromleyvideo.com) in the UK has lots of DVDs, books, videos etc. of all things cycling - grand tours, races, bios, documentaries, dramatisations. Not particularly cheap but the best selection I've seen in a single place, also some of the DVDs are self-produced so I'd imagine are unavailable elsewhere. I think they also have an eBay outlet, you may find some things cheaper on there.

Answer (score 0):

### Great bicycle movies

1. [Top Five Cycling Films of All Time](http://www.goskyride.com/tipsandideas/showarticle/the-top-five-cycling-films-of-all-time)
2. [9 Cycling Movies You Can't Miss](http://www.bicycling.com/news/featured-stories/9-cycling-movies-you-cant-miss)
3. [10 Best Cycling Movies Ever](http://www.stuff.tv/10-best-cycling-movies-ever/news)

Bonus:

[Best Bicycle Movie Scenes](http://blogs.westword.com/showandtell/2012/04/best-bicycle-movie-scenes.php)

### All bicycle movies

1. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_about_bicycles_and_cycling)
2. [Bicycle Universe](http://bicycleuniverse.info/stuff/movies-documentaries.html)
3. [IMDB 1](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls006333040/)
4. [IMDB 2](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls003620851/)

Comment: Can you provide the titles instead of the bare links?

Comment: The links have pictures and plot, I wouldn't spend time on this. But you can copy-paste them if you want...

Comment: wikipedia link is great, lists a lot of titles I've never heard of.

Comment: Link only answers are not really what SE is about. Links are good but answers should at least provide a summary of the content of the link.

Comment: @mattnz questions asking for lists and opinions are not really what SE is about.

Answer (score 0):

[The Armstrong Lie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Armstrong_Lie)

> In 2009 director Alex Gibney set out to film The Road Back, a documentary on cyclist Lance Armstrong's comeback year after a four-year retirement from the sport. Three years later, on October 2012, a doping investigation led to his lifetime ban from competition and the stripping of his seven Tour de France titles, and the documentary was shelved. On January 14, 2013, three hours after his appearance on Oprah, Armstrong went back to Gibney to set the record straight about his career.

Answer (score 0):

If you are into mountain biking at all, I highly recommend any/all of the NWD (New World Disorder) series, and also the films The Collective made.  NWD is pretty much straight up old school bike Pr0n.  Professionals on bikes doing ridiculous things to awesome music.  The collectives movies were a bit more artsy, but very close to the same thing; both sets were well done.

Finally I'd also like to recommend Bang Bang, which was a film that sort of revolved around Aaron Chase and the year he broke his back.  It's very behind the scenes and gave me a very unique perspective on what some of the riders are actually like and how to some extent "the show must go on".